# Discord Movie Bot error - AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Tags: python, api, discord, bots

I have tried to create a discord bot for movies, but I am facing some error, while running the commands. I was able to successfully run the program and the bot shows itself online in my server. However, whenever I enter a command in my server, it shows me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

I have already checked [AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message' (Discord Bot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116872/attributeerror-client-object-has-no-attribute-send-message-discord-bot) and [AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message' (DiscordBot python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482788/attributeerror-client-object-has-no-attribute-send-message-discordbot-pyth) but I am not able to solve my error as this is my first time creating a bot and I am new to using discord.py in general.

Here is my code:

bot.py

```
import discord
import asyncio

class MoviesBot:
    """
        @token String -> the api token for the Discord API
        @movies_provider -> allows searching movies
    """
    def __init__(self, token, movies_provider, subtitles_provider):
        self.__token = token
        self.__movies_provider = movies_provider
        self.__subtitles_provider = subtitles_provider
        self.__client = discord.Client()

        @self.__client.event
        async def on_ready(): await self.handle_ready()

        @self.__client.event
        async def on_message(message): await self.handle_message(message)

    @staticmethod
    def __get_embed_for_query_result(movie, subs, also=[]):
        # Title and Description
        formatted_title = '{} | {}'.format(movie.title, str(movie.year))
        
        description = movie.description + '\n'
        description += "View on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/{})".format(movie.imdb_id)
        
        embed = discord.Embed(title=formatted_title, description=description)
        
        # Thumbnail
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=movie.thumbnail)

        # Download Links
        for download in movie.downloads:
            download_link = "[Download]({})".format(download['url'])
            embed.add_field(name=download['title'], value=download_link, inline=False)
        
        if subs:
            embed.add_field(name="{} Subtitles".format(subs.language), value="[Download Subs]({})".format(subs.download_url))

        # Footer (Other search options)
        if len(also) > 0:
            other_options = ', '.join(['{} ({})'.format(m.title, m.year) for m in also])
            embed.set_footer(text="Did you mean:\n" + other_options)

        return embed

    async def handle_ready(self):
        # Log
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.__client.user.name)
        print(self.__client.user.id)
        print('------')

    @staticmethod
    def is_movies_request(message):
        content = message.content
        # Check if keyword matches
        for keyword in ['!movie', '!movies', '!moviebot', '!moviesbot']:
            # If found a match, return True
            if content.startswith(keyword + ' ') and len(content) > len(keyword + ' '):
                return True

        # Return False in case no keyword matched
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def get_query_from_command(message):
        content = message.content
        # Remove first word
        words = content.split(' ')
        return ' '.join(words[1:])
    
    async def discord_response_for_query(self, query):
        movies = await self.__movies_provider.search_movies(query)
        # If no movies were found
        if len(movies) == 0:
            # present message
            return "Sorry, I didn't find anything.", None
        
        selected_movie = movies[0]
        subtitles = await self.__subtitles_provider.search_subtitles(selected_movie)
        # If only found one movie, return it as single result
        if len(movies) == 1:
            # construct message and present it
            embed = self.__get_embed_for_query_result(selected_movie, subs=subtitles)
            return 'Got It!', embed
        # If found multiple movies, return the best one and other as hints
        elif len(movies) > 1:
            alsoFound = movies[1:]
            # construct message and present it
            embed = self.__get_embed_for_query_result(selected_movie, subs=subtitles, also=alsoFound)
            return'Found some, here is the best one', embed

    async def handle_message(self, message):
        if self.is_movies_request(message):
            # Query movies
            query = self.get_query_from_command(message)
            tmp = await self.__client.send_message(message.channel, 'Proccessing...')
            try:
                body, embed = await self.discord_response_for_query(query)
            except:
                print("Error Occured")
                body, embed = "Oops. Something went wrong.", None
            
            await self.__client.edit_message(tmp, body, embed=embed)

    def start(self):
        # start the bot
        self.__client.run(self.__token)
```

main.py

```
#Movies
from backend.movies.yst_am import YstAmProvider

# Subs
from backend.subtitles.yifysubtitles import YifySubtitlesPorivder
from backend.subtitles.opensubtitles_org import OpenSubsProvider
from backend.subtitles.multiple_sources import MultipleSourcesProvider

# Bot

    from bot import MoviesBot
    from credentials import token
    
    bot = MoviesBot(token, YstAmProvider(), MultipleSourcesProvider([YifySubtitlesPorivder('Hebrew'), OpenSubsProvider('heb', 'Hebrew')]))
    bot.start()
```

This was the error that I received:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Mac/Desktop/Bot/app/bot.py", line 19, in on_message
    async def on_message(message): await self.handle_message(message)
  File "/Users/Mac/Desktop/Bot/app/bot.py", line 100, in handle_message
    tmp = await self.__client.send_message(message.channel, 'Proccessing...')
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewong Hi, I have included the complete error that I received.

Comment: But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116872/attributeerror-client-object-has-no-attribute-send-message-discord-bot) post should answer your question. `Client.send_message` does not exist, you have to send messages using a `TextChannel` or `Context`, among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looking at the documentation for discord.py https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client

The discord.Client class does not have a method called send_message. As mentioned in the link you posted, you can use `message.channel.send("Content")` to send a message.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: As suggested by sir_ and @TheFungusAmongUs, I have referred the docs and successfully solved my problem. Thank you.